# If a permutation distribution is non-normal, what general conclusions can be drawn about it?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, normal-distribution, predictive-models, permutation-test

To validate a complicated ML (machine learning) model, I am using permutation tests to check whether there are any over-fitting problems.

I don't observe a non-normal permutation distribution but I was thinking that if I did, what conclusions could I draw about it?

A normally distributed permutation distribution kind of makes a lot of sense: it is a sum of various kinds of errors. If it was non-normal, I would intuitively start thinking about *something* causing the funny or weird shape.

Is my reasoning correct? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to Cross-Validated!

Answer (score 2):

Sums of random errors are, in general, fairly normally distributed. This is typically the case even if the errors are not. This is implied by the central limit distribution.

Very often, if you have a random variable that is the sum of other random variables and its not approximately normally distributed, this is because a very small number of the random variables dominate the sum. So in your permutation example, perhaps most of your values range from 0-1, but one of them is 1000. You would then expect a very bimodal distribution, basically caused by that single value.